# NullPointerException while populating an Array or a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to populate an array with the another array of values and doing the same with lists but getting null pointer exception for arrays and nothing happened using the list. below is the code snippet:

```
public class EMPTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Array
        EMP[] emps = new EMP[(5)];
        String[] values = {"2","4","6","8","10"};
        for(int i=0; i<emps.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++){
                emps[i].setId(values[j]); //NullPointerException happened here
                emps[i].setName(values[j]);
                emps[i].setDep(values[j]);
                emps[i].setSal(values[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("emps: "+emps);
        //List
        List<EMP> empL = new ArrayList<EMP>(5);
        List<String> val = new ArrayList<String>();
        val.add("a");
        val.add("b");
        val.add("c");
        val.add("d");
        val.add("e");

        List<EMP> storedEMPs = null;
        for(EMP e : empL){
            for(String vals : val){
                e.setId(vals);
                e.setName(vals);
                e.setSal(vals);
                e.setDep(vals);
                storedEMPs.add(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Populated EMPs: "+storedEMPs);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.EMPTest.main(EMPTest.java:12)
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this code using a debugger?

Comment: `EMP[] emps = new EMP[(5)]` just creates an array and fill it with `null`

Comment: You have to initialize each member of array when u doing some operation on them.

Comment: Never invoke any method on null object.

Comment: Your nested loops make no sense either.Once you fixed the `NullPointerException`, you will overwrite the values of one object several times in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because nothing is stored in array

When you do this:

```
    EMP[] emps = new EMP[(5)];
```

You just create an array with enough space to store 5 `EMP`, nothing inside this array.

Try:

```
    String[] values = {"2","4","6","8","10"};
    for(int i=0; i<emps.length; i++){
        emps[i] = new EMP();//Need to initialize object here!
        for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++){
            emps[i].setId(values[j]); 
            emps[i].setName(values[j]);
            emps[i].setDep(values[j]);
            emps[i].setSal(values[j]);
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

I think you want to do this, as calling a nested loop in the above case doesn't make any sense:

```
    for(int i=0; i<emps.length; i++){
        emps[i] = new EMP();//Need to initialize object here!
        emps[i].setId(values[i]); 
        emps[i].setName(values[i]);
        emps[i].setDep(values[i]);
        emps[i].setSal(values[i]);    
    }
```

Comment: That will fix the `NullPointerException` but think about the code you have taken over from the question. It doesn’t make any sense to call the set methods multiple times on the same object.

Comment: Why is this the accepted anwser ! it make no sense ! you always override emps[i] with the last value of `values`

Comment: @Holger you mean the part when `emps[i].setId()` is called multiple time?

Comment: @Pham Trung: `setId` and all other subsequent method calls. You are calling them 25 times but have only 5 objects. And all 5 objects will contain the same values at the end.

Comment: @Holger, I have suggested how to fix it in the `Note` part.

Answer (score 2):

You created an empty array of size 5:

`EMP[] emps = new EMP[5];`

But then you try to access an index who is naturally equals to null. (`emps[0] is null`)
You have to initialize each object of your array before trying to access it ! :

```
[...]
EMP[] emps = new EMP[(5)];
String[] values = {"2","4","6","8","10"};
for(int i=0; i<emps.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++){
        emps[i] = new EMP(...); //Initialize it first !
        emps[i].setId(values[j]);
        emps[i].setName(values[j]);
        emps[i].setDep(values[j]);
        emps[i].setSal(values[j]);
    }
}
```

Moreover here you will always override `emps[i]` with the last value contained in your array `values`.

I think your code is somewhere wrong and you should better write:

```
EMP[] emps = new EMP[5];
String[] values = {"2","4","6","8","10"};
for(int i=0; i<emps.length; i++){
    emps[i] = new EMP(...);
    emps[i].setId(values[i]);
    emps[i].setName(values[i]);
    emps[i].setDep(values[i]);
    emps[i].setSal(values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`emp[i]` is null. you have to set `emp[i] = new EMP()` before calling the setter.

```
emps[i]  = new EMP();
for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++){
   emps[i].setId(values[j]); //NullPointerException happened here
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your array initialized correctly `EMP[] emps = new EMP[(5)];` but at each array position there is nothing, which means it is NULL, so you are getting NullPointer.
You need to first initialize each position like `emps[0] = new EMP(); emps[1] = new EMP(); ...` and then you can execute methods over it.